# bigQuery: PartialFailureError on table insert

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert data row to bigQuery table as follows:

```
await bigqueryClient
          .dataset(DATASET_ID)
          .table(TABLE_ID)
          .insert(row);
```

But I get a `PartialFailureError` when deploying the cloud function.

The table schem has a name (string) and campaigns (record/repeated) fields which I created manually from the console.

```
hotel_name  STRING  NULLABLE    
campaigns   RECORD  REPEATED    
  campaign_id   STRING  NULLABLE    
  platform_id   NUMERIC NULLABLE    
  platform_name STRING  NULLABLE    
  reporting_id  STRING  NULLABLE
```

And the data I'm inserting is an object like this:

```
      const row = {
        hotel_name: hotel_name,//string
        campaigns: {
            id: item.id,//string
            platform_id: item.platform_id,//int
            platform_name: item.platform_name,//string
            reporting_id: item.reporting_id,//string
          },
      };
```

The errors logged don't give much clue about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test it seems that there are 2 errors here. First is that you have `campaign_id` in schema while `id` in JSON.

2nd thing is related with format of REPEATED mode data in JSON. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) mentions following:

> . Notice that the `addresses` column contains an array of values (indicated by `[ ]`). The multiple addresses in the array are the repeated data. The multiple fields within each address are the nested data.

It's not so straight in mentioned document (probably can be found somewhere else) however when you use REPEATED mode you should use brackets `[]`.

I tested it shortly on my side and it seems that it should work like this:

```
const row = {
        hotel_name: hotel_name,//string
        campaigns: [ {
            campaign_id: item.id,//string
            platform_id: item.platform_id,//int
            platform_name: item.platform_name,//string
            reporting_id: item.reporting_id,//string
          }, ]
      };
```

Answer (score 4):

These errors suck. The actual info about what went wrong can be found in the `errors` property on the PartialFailureError. In https://www.atdatabases.org we reformat the error to make this easier using: https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/atdatabases/blob/0e1a033264aac33deaff2ab753796049e623ab86/packages/bigquery/src/implementation/BigQueryDriver.ts#L211